# how to make Angular service only module scooped if its not a lazy loaded module

Tags: angular

So i m trying to make a module have a service which is module scoped. I have implemented a shared module which i would like to have it with a utils service only singleton to its components. other modules can only have instances of the utils service.

when i import this shared module in the app module, than somehow the utils service becomes singleton eventhough its not provided inside of the app module.

what is the logic behind of it ? And how can i achieve this when its not a route module which is lazy loaded ?

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [FilterComponent],
  imports: [
  ],
  exports: [
    FilterComponent
  ],
  providers: [DataService]
})
export class SharedModule {
}
```

---

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    SharedModule,
    CommonModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: SharedModule
})
export class UtilsService {
  constructor() {
   console.log("created")
  }
}
```

Comment: `UtilsService` lives in the SharedModule? You want the `UtilsService` to be only accessible within the components declared in the `SharedModule`?

Comment: You should have components with modules and import a shared module there not at the app level. Wherever the components are declared that’s where it should be imported.

Comment: yes i want to have utils service just accessable in the shared module. no other module should have access to utils service